# Enter Button on Soft KeyBoard - Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

Im using a a Single Line Edit Text , so when i click on Edit text box, im getting "Go" in place of Enter button. But i want Enter key in place of "Go" key . How can i do this .. Please some one can give solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but you can try **`android:imeOptions="actionDone"`**, in short you need to try `android:imeOptions` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
    EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText); // Your EditText

    Button button = findViewById(R.id.button); // Your Button

    editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
    editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);

    editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                button.performClick(); // Imitation of pressing the button

                // Hide the keyboard after pressing
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**