# onClickListener to a keyboard button

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have a EditText field in my activity. The user can change the text in that field using the virtual keyboard. Once the user presses the enter key on the keyboard, I want to perform some action. So, how do I implement a setOnClickListener to the enter button on the keyboard?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use `onKeyListener` for checking Enter press

for e.g..

```
edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction()!=KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            return false;
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER ){
            //your necessary codes...
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

for more information, check the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html)

Also you can see that [example](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.view.View.OnKeyListener)

Comment: thanks this worked perfectly! i only had to change the `editext` to the one i was using in my code, and add a `)` at the end to complete the `(new OnKeyListener() {`, otherwise fantastic. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Possible Duplicate to ones below,

[Use "ENTER" key on softkeyboard instead of clicking button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451374/use-enter-key-on-softkeyboard-instead-of-clicking-button)

[Enter Button on Soft KeyBoard - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790672/enter-button-on-soft-keyboard-android)

Hope these help

Answer (score 2):

Set a special listener to be called when an action is performed on the text view. This will be called when the enter key is pressed, or when an action supplied to the IME is selected by the user. Setting this means that the normal hard key event will not insert a newline into the text view, even if it is multi-line; holding down the ALT modifier will, however, allow the user to insert a newline character.

```
edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(final TextView v, final int actionId, final KeyEvent event) {
                if ((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)) {
                    //perform your action
                    //button.performClick();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a little bit of research for you and found this:
[How to override the <ENTER> key behaviour of the virtual keyboard in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272142/how-to-override-the-enter-key-behaviour-of-the-virtual-keyboard-in-android)

It explains how to change the action of the enter key.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

try

KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener ... Listener for virtual keyboard events.

for further actions ...

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener.html